To have one translation file per view
I work with vue.js (version 2) and I have a translation block in every vue file like this:
abc.vue
<i18n>   
{
    "fr": {
        "settings": "Conf"
    },
    "en": {
        "settings": "Configuration"
    }
} 
</i18n>
    
<template>
.... {{ $t('settings') }} ...
</template>

i18n.js
function loadLocaleMessages () {
  const locales = require.context(
    '../locales',
    true,
    /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i
  )
  const messages = {}
  locales.keys().forEach((key) => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1]
      messages[locale] = locales(key)
    }
  })
  return messages
}

So, it works but I would like to have one translation file per vue file.
I would like to have :
in "fr" directory :
abc.json
{
"settings": "Conf"
}
in "en" directory :
abc.json
{
"settings": "Configuration"
}
How can I do that?
Many thanks.

Do you want to create a separate translation file (JSON) for each language?

I have a separate translation JSON file for each langage. But I would like to optimize the translations :  I would like to have one translation JSON file for one "vue" and per langague. Thus, if a have a "abc.vue" file, I would like to have under "FR" repertory a file named "abc.json" and to have under "EN" repertory a file named "abc.json"

Okay Got it. Thanks for the explanation.

So you can achieve this by follow below steps:-

create directories for each language and place the translations files corresponding to each vue component.

Modify i18n.js as below
 import Vue from "vue";
 import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";
 import fs from "fs";
 import path from "path";

 Vue.use(VueI18n);

  function loadLocaleMessages() {
   const localesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "./assets/locales");
    const messages = {};

 fs.readdirSync(localesDir).forEach((locale) => {
  const localePath = path.join(localesDir, locale);
  if (fs.statSync(localePath).isDirectory()) {
    messages[locale] = {};
    fs.readdirSync(localePath).forEach((file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(localePath, file);
      const namespace = path.basename(file, ".json");
      messages[locale][namespace] = JSON.parse(
        fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf-8")
      );
    });
  }
});

return messages;
 }



 function createI18n() {
 const messages = loadLocaleMessages();
 return new VueI18n({
   locale: "fr", // set locale
   fallbackLocale: "fr", // set fallback locale
   messages, // set locale messages
  });
 }

 export default createI18n;


Update main.js as below
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import createI18n from "./i18n";

const i18n = createI18n();

new Vue({
  i18n,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");



By following these above steps you can achieve this.
Here is the code sandbox for the same.
